# Assign vectors by reference

Tags: c++, reference, variable-assignment

I want to make a vector of valarray-types inside a class, in which each element of said vector references an element of a vector of some struct-type inside the same class. Schematically, I have

```
struct particle{
   valarray<double> x(2);        //x has 2 components
};  

class SPH{
   vector<particle> ps(1000);    //ps has 1000 particles
   vector<valarray> y(1000);
   void RK4_step();
};

void SPH::RK4_step(){
   for(int a=0; a<1000; a++)
      y[a] = ps[a].x;            //HERE
}
```

Is it possible do the assignment in (HERE) by reference, in some way?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this? If all elements of `y` refer to elements of `ps` what did you gain this way?

Comment: With this change, I can use overloaded vector-class operations on y (something I am already using in my real code), whereas I'd need to overload the particle-class operators to do that with ps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

```
struct particle{
   valarray<double> x(2);        //x has 2 components
};

class SPH{
   vector<particle> ps(1000);    //ps has 1000 particles
   vector<std::reference_wrapper<valarray<double>>> y(1000);
   void RK4_step();
};

void SPH::RK4_step(){
   for(int a=0; a<1000; a++)
      y[a] = std::ref(ps[a].x);
}
```

***Warning***. Vector elements are not guaranteed to occupy the same spot in memory after the vector resizes.
If `ps` is resized at any time, you will loose all your references. In that case I would recommend [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)

Comment: `valarray` is missing `<double>`

Comment: I am safe regarding this warning, the vector won't be resized. Thanks!

Comment: @RenanNobuyukiHirayama, you're welcome. Please accept by pressing the check mark beside the answer

Answer (score 0):

What's the point?

Why not just provide an accessor function to get the `valarray` element instead?

```
struct particle{
   valarray<double> x(2);        //x has 2 components
};  

class SPH{
   vector<particle> ps(1000);    //ps has 1000 particles
   valarray<double>& va(size_t n) { return ps[n].x; }
   const valarray<double>& va(size_t n) const { return ps[n].x; }
   // ...
};
```